# Emacs: when byte-compile, it deletes any content inside foldings

Tags: emacs, compilation, folding

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

I'm trying to byte-compile my init.le file.
The problem I have is that the resulting init.lec file is empty!
After some test I realised that any content inside foldings (that would be ;;{{{ ;;}}}) is deleted.

Anyone has any idea how to prevent this, apart from stop using foldings :-D (folding.el to be more precise).

I also tried to change the foldings syntax. 
It wasn't easy, but when I got it work, Emacs deleted the content of the foldings with the new syntax! Crazy eh?

Cheers!

UPDATE:

This is my [init.el](https://github.com/rafaelgp/emacs-serendipity/blob/master/init.el) file (sorry for the typo above)

I use [folding.le](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/folding.el) to keep everything tidy.

Basically, what it does is contract and expand the content inside the ;;{{{ ;;}}} tags

So when everything is folded, my init.el file looks like this:

```
(message "Loading Emacs!")

;;{{{ FIRST...
;;{{{ DIRECTORIES...
;;{{{ PACKAGES...
;;{{{ INTERFACE...
;;{{{ EDITOR...
;;{{{ FUNCTIONS...
;;{{{ HOOKS...
;;{{{ PACKAGES...
;;{{{ LAST...

(message "Emacs Loaded!")
```

After byte compile, this the resulting init.elc file:

```
ELC
;;; Compiled by rafaelgp@RAFAELGP-PC on Thu Apr 19 17:37:20 2012
;;; from file c:/Users/rafaelgp/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/init.el
;;; in Emacs version 24.0.92.1
;;; with all optimizations.

;;; This file uses dynamic docstrings, first added in Emacs 19.29.

;;; This file does not contain utf-8 non-ASCII characters,
;;; and so can be loaded in Emacs versions earlier than 23.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


(byte-code "\300\301!\210\300\302!\207" [message "Loading Emacs!" "Emacs Loaded!"] 2)
```

Cheers

Comment: first of its not `init.le` but `init.el`. I am not what you mean by foldings, please provide any example. You shouldn't be looking at byte compiled `elc` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.  It seems to work for me, but I had to comment out some things which I didn't have installed, like viper.  I use a modified version of [this fold mode](http://uuid.com/~marcus/computing/fold-mode.html) and haven't had any problems.  At the very least you can add advice around byte compilation to turn off folding, like

```
(defadvice byte-compile-file (around turn-off-folding activate)
  (turn-off-folding-mode)
  ad-do-it
  (turn-on-folding-mode))
```

Hopefully that will solve your problem.  Nevertheless I might try a different folding mode.

Comment: Well done!!! I replaced folding.el for fold.el a that did the trick. Now init.elc is compiled properly. Fold.el works ok so far. It's a shame it uses two different keymaps to open and close folds, instead of just one to toggle the status. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm sure the features of the two modes are different, but if you're happy with `fold.el` then I guess it's okay.